# how to pass parameter as a object using angularjs mvc c#?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

i want to pass pass value as a object using angularjs with ajax call.i have create one class in c#.and now i am call service in angularjs and pass object but controller side i am not getting this value.

i have create this  class in c#:

```
 public class FType
 {
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Way { get; set; }
 }
```

i have write this code for call controller.js :

```
var Params = {
        Type: 'All',           
        Way: ''
    };
$scope.dtOptions = Userservice.GetAllUserss(DTOptionsBuilder, Params)
```

this is my service.js code:

```
this.GetAllUserss = function (DTOptionsBuilder, Params) {        
    var response = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption("ajax", {
        dataSrc: "data",
        url: "/admin/getuserlist",
        type: "POST",
        data: Params            
    });
    return response;
};
```

this is my c# method:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("getuserlist")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult getuserlist(FType T) // here i am always getting null
    {
    }
```

any one how can getting this value from c# side please let me know.

Comment: send string then deseriralize it

Comment: how?can you please tell me you mean json.stringfy()?

Answer (score 0):

```
    this.GetAllUserss = function (DTOptionsBuilder, Params) {        
    var response = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption("ajax", {
        dataSrc: "data",
        url: "/admin/getuserlist?T=",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.Stringify(Params)            
    });
    return response;
};

public ActionResult getuserlist(string T)
{

}
```

Try this you must be getting the data in the service, then deserialize it to the object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stringify the data to a json string, the MVC default json serializer will take care of the rest

Try it like this:

```
this.GetAllUserss = function (DTOptionsBuilder, Params) {        
    var response = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption("ajax", {
        dataSrc: "data",
        url: "/admin/getuserlist",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.Stringify(Params) 
    });
    return response;
};
```